# how to get href value from javascript onclick attribute in python using scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, scrapy

```html
<td class="headerStyle">
   <input type="image" 
       name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvfacletails$ctl19$lnkView" 
       id="lnkView" title="View" src="images/view.png" 
       onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvfaculetails$ctl19$lnkView", "", false, "", "viewculty.aspx?FacultyID=Li9S-20151", false, false))">
</td>
```

How to extract this href `viewculty.aspx?FacultyID=Li9S-20151` from above javascript `onclick` in python using scrapy?

Comment: a regular expression?

Comment: what is the best way to extract that link and to parse through callback in python scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
href = response.xpath('//input[@id="lnkView"]/@onclick').re_first( r'([^"]+\?[^"]+)' )
```

Above I'm using regex and searching for `?` and surrounding unquoted  symbols